# Help needed on Green's theorem.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Using Green's Theorem, find the area of the region formed by the intersection of

$$x^2 + y^2 \leq2 \text{ and } y\geq1$$.

Comment: Do you know the formula to calculate the area using green?

Comment: @Aram yeah i know the basic about green theorem but not much.

Comment: try to apply green to $\underset{R}{\int \int}  dA$ where $R$ is your region

Comment: @rohit you could read about [Green's theorem](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/GreensTheorem.aspx).

Comment: i am not able to find P and Q. 
This is different to what examples are given in that link.

Comment: Its the exaple in the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

Green's Theorem can only be applied if a vector field is involved (you mention no P or Q so Green's can't be used). Fortunately, you do not need Green's Theorem to find the area of this region. A simple double integral over the region R will give you the area. That is,

$A = \iint_R 1 dA$

You can do this either using Cartesian or polar coordinates (to find the limits of integration simply examine the range over which each variable varies).